# matplotlib legend showing double errorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why is matplotlib is showing two error bars? I think it may have something to do with the asymmetric error bars.

[image]

You can reproduce the problem with this:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.errorbar([1,2,3],[3,4,2],yerr=[[1,2,0.5]]*2, label='data')
<Container object of 3 artists>
>>> plt.legend()
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x10b82f590>
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: Which version of python and matplotlib? I can't reproduce it with python2.7 and matplotlib 1.1.0

Comment: Python 2.7.2 and matplotlib 1.1.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can set the number of points in legend:

```
plt.legend(numpoints=1)
```